# Number of polygons in a random collection of dots

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

I assumed it was $\sum\limits_{i=3}^n \binom{n}{i}$. Am I right?  I'm not sure if I'm using the right terminology to search online.  Does this problem have a name? Could someone point me to a standard proof and/or recommend some good tests for it.

Comment: Just to clarify: If the points are truly random, then none of them will be collinear, is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assuming that any selection of dots makes exactly one polygon.  You need to clarify what sorts of polygon you allow.  If three dots are in a straight line the triangle is degenerate.  The four corners of a square also allow a second polygon if you allow sides to cross.  If you insist the polygon be convex, there are sets of points that do not make a polygon.  Even if you prohibit self-intersections there are groups of points that determine more than one polygon.  The two below can be translated so the vertices match.
[image]

If you allow self-intersecting polygons and prohibit three colinear points it is simple.  Pick a set of points as in your sum, but multiply each term by $(i-1)!$ for the ways to order the points in a circle and divide by $2$ for the number of ways to go around the circle.  This gives http://oeis.org/A002807, which begins $1, 7, 37, 197, 1172, 8018, 62814, 556014, 5488059, 59740609, 710771275$

Comment: You're right, I was assuming that! Is it too late to edit the question? I was assuming that if I had some n-gon A1A2...An and there were some pair (or more) of Ai which were on the same edge of the gon, the gon would be reduced to an n-```number-of-degenerate-points```+1-gon or partitioned. So for the square, if I'm thinking of the same cross-sided-shape, you'd have two triangles. To what extent does that change things? If you've got a minute, could you add hyperlink for "convex... sets of points that do not make a polygon" and "groups of points that determine more than one polygon"?

Comment: For a set of points that do not make a convex polygon, think of a triangle with a point inside or the example in my answer.  For groups that determine more than one polygon, I gave an example and David G. Stork another one.  When there are more points there can be many polygons.  The point of the square turning into a bow tie is that the intersection point is not one of the selected points, so by some definitions that is still a quadrilateral.  You shouldn't start counting until you have a clear definition of what you are counting.

Comment: Thanks, I saw those examples but I was hoping for more examples. In any case, are you familiar with any approaches to counts for each/either of those cases?

Comment: No, not at all.  I suspect if you exclude self-intersecting polygons there is no simple answer because the number will depend on the locations of the points.  If you allow self-intersecting polygons and prohibit three colinear points it is simple.  Pick a set of points as in your sum, but multiply each term by $(i-1)!$ for the ways to order the points in a circle and divide by $2$ for the number of ways to go around the circle.  This gives http://oeis.org/A002807, which begins $1, 7, 37, 197, 1172, 8018, 62814, 556014$

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer (so don't downvote), but a demonstration that @crystalsnowlion's "answer" is incorrect.  After all, once you've selected $i$ points, there are typically more than one polygon determined by them:

[image]